# The most efficient way to get text width in android?

Tags: android

I need to detect the biggest text size for the text that fits in (width, height). What is the most fast way of getting text size value?

I've tried to iterate text size in for loop and get `Paint.getTextBounds()` but it takes a lot of time and the whole invocation takes few seconds. The paint typeface is `Typeface.MONOSPACE` which should help to save time as char width are equal. Is there any dependency between text size and char width to avoid invoking `Paint.getTextBounds()` ? The task is pretty similar to getting text size for TextView for `match_parent` width and height, so does anybody know how to do it quickly?

Comment: I'm not sure but, Paint.getTextBounds() might not considering Typeface.MONOSPACE. Can't you just calculate the bounds for lets say space character and use the value to calculate how many characters you can put in to the area instead of calling Paint.getTextBounds() repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, sure. But i should iterate text size to calculate total line width for each text size and it takes too much time too

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `Typeface.MONOSPACE`, you don't have to calculate the text bounds neither for each character nor for each text size.

Let say you have variable `paint`, which it's text size set 12 for start. You want to fill the area `width`,`height` with text. Now

```
Rect initialBounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(" ", 0, 1, initialBounds);
float initialTextSize = 12, increase = 2, currentSize = 12;
int charCount = text.length();//the char count we want to print
int maxCharCount = 0;//max count of chars we can print at currentSize.
do{
    currentSize += increase;
    float charWidth = initialBounds.right * currentSize / initialTextSize;
    float charHeight = initialBounds.bottom * currentSize / initialTextSize;
    int charPerLine = width / charWidth;
    int lineCount = height / charHeight;
    maxCharCount = charPerLine * lineCount;
}
while(maxCharCount > charCount);
currentSize -= increase;//this is the size we are looking for.
```

After that you can just call `paint.setTextSize(currentSize);` and draw the text.

*I didn't test the code, but it should work. You would need some modifications if you want to also be able to decrease the text size below the initial text size if necessary.*

Comment: Are you sure it's linear dependency between text size and width so one can just use `initialBounds.right * currentSize / initialTextSize`? If that is true one can just calculate max text size as `final_text_size = max_width / cur_width * cur_text_size` without iteration